# Error accessing vaule, avalible from global game scope. Canvas and JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a small issue. I am "working" on some canvas stuff, and I have a strange problem that I can't resolve.
I have Player and Bricks that are interacting. Simple collision checks. I did create a global function that will resolve all my collisions, but there is an issue accessing bricks position.

collision.js

```
export const collisionDetection = (player, gameObejct) => {
  //* *  player position
  let playerBootom = player.position.y + player.height;
  let playerTop = player.position.y;
  let playerLeft = player.position.x;
  let playerRight = player.position.x + player.width;

  //* *   brick position
  let objectTop = gameObejct.position.y;
  let objectBottom = gameObejct.position.y + gameObejct.height;
  let objectLeft = gameObejct.position.x - player.width;
  let objectRight = gameObejct.position.x + gameObejct.width + player.width;
  let objectLeftBottom =
    gameObejct.position.x - gameObejct.height - player.width;

  //* * brick player collison checks
  if (
    playerBootom >= objectTop &&
    playerTop <= objectBottom &&
    playerLeft >= objectLeft &&
    playerRight <= objectRight
  ) {
    player.position.y = gameObejct.position.y + gameObejct.gap - player.height;
  }
};
```

Here I am using `gameObject` as a reference to all my game objects.

I am using this currently in my brick.js

```
import { collisionDetection } from './collision';

class Brick {
  constructor(game, position) {
    const thisBrick = this;

    thisBrick.game = game;
    thisBrick.width = 80;
    thisBrick.height = 20;
    thisBrick.gap = 1;
    thisBrick.position = position;
    thisBrick.color = '#E8E111';
  }

  draw(context) {
    const thisBrick = this;

    context.fillStyle = thisBrick.color;
    context.fillRect(
      thisBrick.position.x,
      thisBrick.position.y,
      thisBrick.width - thisBrick.gap,
      thisBrick.height
    );
  }

  update() {
    const thisBrick = this;
    collisionDetection(thisBrick.game.player, thisBrick);
  }
}

export default Brick;
```

But if i use this in player.js `update()`. `collisionDetection(thisPlayer, thisPlayer.game.bricks)` I am getting error that `Cannot read property 'y' of undefined`.
My bricks are generated in levels.js

```
import Brick from './brick';

export function buildLevel(game, level) {
  let bricks = [];

  level.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((brick, brickIndex) => {
      if (brick === 1) {
        let position = {
          /*800 width 8 bricks per row */
          x: 80 * brickIndex,
          y: 50 + 20 * rowIndex,
        };
        bricks.push(new Brick(game, position));
      }
    });
  });

  return bricks;
}

export const level1 = [
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  // [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  // [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];
```

Not sure why this is not working this way. `console.log()` are showing all Bricks attributes, when I access it from the player with `console.logs(thisPlayer.game.bricks)`. `bricks` array is initialized in game.js

```
class Game {
  constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
    const thisGame = this;
    thisGame.gameHeight = gameHeight;
    thisGame.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    thisGame.bricks = [];
    thisGame.groundFriction = 0.8;
    thisGame.gravity = 0.6;
    thisGame.airResitance = 0.9;
  }

  start() {
    const thisGame = this;

    thisGame.bricks = buildLevel(thisGame, level1);
    thisGame.player = new Player(thisGame);

    thisGame.gameObjects = [thisGame.player, ...thisGame.bricks];

    new InputHandler(thisGame.player, thisGame);
  }

  draw(context) {
    const thisGame = this;

    thisGame.gameObjects.forEach((object) => object.draw(context));
  }

  update(deltaTime) {
    const thisGame = this;
    thisGame.gameObjects.forEach((object) => object.update(deltaTime));
  }
}

export default Game;
```

Any help or clues for this need. Thanks for help
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-smoke-8qh0o?file=/src/collision.js)

Comment: `collisionDetection(thisPlayer, thisPlayer.game.bricks);` in `player.js`,  bricks is an array and you are trying to read position from it directly without iterating it or finding the right brick if you need only one.

Comment: hmm okay. thanks this makes sens.